# Executing Karate scenarios calling external JAR from VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jar, external, karate

I use Karate as standalone JAR, and for writing scenarios I've installed Visual Source Code with the "karate-runner" plugin as IDE support.
I use an external jar for encryption treatments.
The trouble is that, when I execute a Karate scenario from Visual Source Code (for debuggig purpose), my external jar is not taken into account, and during execution, I get the message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GenerateSign" in the console.
I've no problem when I launch the scenario directly in command line like :

```
Karate.bat mytest.feature
```

With the content of karate.bat is :

```
java -cp karate.jar;Sign.jar;. com.intuit.karate.Main %*
```

So, how to configure the tools in order to execute my karate scenarios from VScode taking into account my external jar too?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is you haven't updated the "karateCli" property in your launch.json debug configuration.  Can you try to update it including your additional jar file and try again.

**EDIT**

Based on what command line does work in your batch file you should update your "Karate Runner" extensions settings as shown below in the images.

For running tests from Codelens with "Run Karate Test(s)"
[image]

For running tests with VSCode debugger
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

For a debug session with VScode, do i put for example? :
"karateCli": "java -jar karate.jar Sign.jar -d"
It don't works...

And, if I don't launch a debug session, just launch a Karate test by clicking on "Run Karate Test" link in a *.feature file : how to take into account an external jar ?
In the Terminal, I see always :
java -cp karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main
It's not depending on what I write in the karate.bat file.

Please help !

Comment: I would reference the Karate jar and debugging documentation at https://github.com/intuit/karate.  Possibly try setting "karateCli": "java -cp karate.jar:Sign.jar -d"

Comment: When not debugging you can update the same command by going to "file" or "menu" > "preferences" > "settings" > "Extensions" > "Karate Runner" > "Karate Jar: Command Line Args"

Comment: Thanks, but by modifying the command line Args parameter, like this :
"java -cp ./karate.jar;./sign.jar;. com.intuit.karate.Main"
when I execute a Karate scenario by clicking on it, I get the following error :
+ java -cp ./karate.jar;./sign.jar;. com.intuit.karate.Main c:\_Kar ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (com.intuit.karate.Main:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
I don't know why... Do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you try using a colon not a semi-colon between the jar file paths.  If you still have trouble if you can post a sample project somewhere that demonstrates the issue that might help solve this faster.

Comment: Using colon fails too. In the doc, colon must be used on mac / linux, and semi-colon must be used on Windows (which is my case). With colon, the issue is : The class com.intuit.karate.Main can not be found.

Comment: Please see my latest EDIT in my answer above ^^.  Ultimately you want the command that runs in the console when you click "Run Karate Tests" to match what is working when you run manually on the command line.  If you're still having problems please let me know what command Karate Runner is trying to run on the command line.  Also as mentioned before if you have a project that I can look at I can try to help solve this quicker.

Comment: Finally, I've found how to configure the Karate-runner plugin for VSCode, in order to run tests from Codelens with "Run Karate Test(s)" and to run tests with VSCode debugger. I simply put the classpath into single quotes, like this in the Karate runner settings : java -cp 'karate.jar;sign.jar;.' com.intuit.karate.Main and in the launch.json file : "karateCli": "java -cp 'karate.jar;sign.jar;.' com.intuit.karate.Main -d"

Comment: @J-Marc thanks for letting us know about this we will update our documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you simply are on the wrong version. Dir you try 0.9.5 ?

Here are the instructions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner

For those coming across this in the future, you can use this as an additional reference: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide

Comment: Yes, I use the 0.9.5 version.
But in the instruction page you indicate, I don't see what I exactly should do. Sorry, but I don't know the Java environment at all !
Can you explain me in detail, please?